# Как задать ширину колонок таблицы из массива JSON c помощью JQuery?

Tags: html, jquery, css, json, bootstrap

Есть массив JSON  ***["27.798634","145.57683400000002","223.353834"]*** и таблица Bootstrap, состоящая из трех колонок. Как с помощью JQuery задать каждой колонке значение ширины соответствующее значениям в массиве JSON?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Bordered Table</h2>
  <p>The .table-bordered class adds borders to a table:</p>            
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скрипт для изменения ширины простой, только `Bootstrap` задает свои стили для таблиц растягивая их по ширине. Так что ширина точно такой как в массиве не будет.

```
const column = ["23.798634", "145.57683400000002", "233.353834"];

$('.table').find('thead th').each((i, th) => {
  $(th).width(column[i]);
});
```